# JCR Node.getReferences() doesn't work

Tags: groovy, jackrabbit, jcr, sling

I'm using Apache Sling and its Jackrabbit JCR 2.0. With the latest libs.

Now I'm trying to get references to my node as following groovy code shows

```
node.getWeakReferences("track").toList().size()
```

returns 1

but

```
node.getWeakReferences().toList().size()
```

returns 0

According to the JCR API docs `node.getWeakReferences()` should return all weak references:

> getWeakReferences() - This method returns all WEAKREFERENCE properties that refer to this node and that are accessible through the current Session.

What could I do to get all references without knowing their reference name?

Comment: This should work ... what exact version of Jackrabbit are you using?

Comment: it's jcr.repository.version: 2.4.2

Comment: That's relatively old, you might want to try 2.8.0

Comment: new apache sling 7 release uses jcr.repository.version 2.6.5 and doesn't work either

Comment: Can you not call toList() and consume the iterator directly? I suspect some inconsistencies in the iterator implementation but can't be sure